# How can I add a relationship many to many with existing objects ID's array in entity framework 4.4?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I've been struggling for days with this matter and believe me this is my last resource, I've tried many things, but since there are so many different Entity Framework Versions I do not know which one could work for me if there is any EF expert I beg you help.

Well I am trying to insert many to many relationships into my database which are several and I've stored the existing IDs from the Entities in arrays. So now I have:

```
Catalog_List_T c = new Catalog_List_T();
c.Name = name;
c.Description = description;
int[] langs = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(lags.Split(';'), Convert.ToInt32);
foreach (var a in langs)
                {
                    Language_T language = new Language_T() { ID = a };
                    _db.Language_T.Attach(language);                                              
                    _db.Catalog_List_T.AddObject(c);
                    //_db.SaveChanges();
                }


                int[] skills = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(skillss.Split(';'), Convert.ToInt32);
                foreach (var a in skills)
                {
                    Support_Skill_T skill = new Support_Skill_T() { ID = a };
                    _db.Support_Skill_T.Attach(skill);                        
                    _db.Catalog_List_T.AddObject(c);
                    //_db.SaveChanges();
                }

_db.Catalog_List_T.AddObject(c);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

I have no problems here, I mean I dont get into any exception, First data is inserted but these many to many relationships are not. So Name and Description get inserted but not the relationships between my Catalog_List_T instance and Support_Skill_T or Language_T, these do not happen. If anyone can help or comment anything will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I get exception context is tracking element with the same Key, something like that. Check my ER diagram.

[image: Here are the relationships in the EF diagram.]

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually create a relationship between the catalog list `c` and the languages and skills. You must do this by adding languages and skills to the corresponding navigation collections of the catalog list entity. Basically you have to replace `_db.Catalog_List_T.AddObject(c);` in the two loops by the lines:

```
c.Languages.Add(language);
```

...and...

```
c.Skills.Add(skill);
```

Comment: Hey thank you Slauma I've seen several of your posts, I think your answer it's right, but I can't mark it correct until I stop getting errors, since I want to map the same table three times but in different columns I am getting an exception, something like the context can't track two entities with the same key. I just want to be sure this is the right answer hope you understand and maybe help me. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: @GJenyRamirez: This exception could occur if the integers in your `langs` or `skills` arrays are not unique. You can make them unique by adding `.Distinct().ToArray()` at the end of the two `ConvertAll` calls.

Comment: thank you for your help, those arrays are INT arrays and they have unique elements I've checked them, they cannot have repeated values, so the repetition must occur somewhere else, I think probably because I have four connections between the same two tables in many-to-many relationships. See my update. Thank you very much for your help.